# Group of symmetric invertible matrices

Tags: matrices, group-theory

All $2 \times 2$ symmetric invertible matrices form an infinite abelian group under matrix multiplication.

Is the above statement true?

I know it has identity, associative property and inverses exist.

Product of invertible matrices is invertible and product of symmetric matrices is symmetric only if the matrices commute. Hence the answer should be no. They don't even form a Group.

Is my argument correct?

Comment: product of invertible matrices is invertible as $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$. $2$nd point is right

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

Then $AB \neq BA$. (Note that $\det (AB) \neq 0$.)

Also, $(AB)^T \neq AB$.

Comment: I know it is not abelian group. But is it a Group? No ,right? Because AB is not symmetric, correct?

Comment: Correct, I should have added that.