# Let $G$ be the set of all $2 \times 2$ symmetric invertible matrices with real entries

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be the set of all $2 \times 2$ symmetric invertible matrices with real entries then with matrix multiplication, $G$ is not from a group. Help me to find a counter examples.

Comment: Duplicated. Here is the answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979491/group-of-symmetric-invertible-matrices

Comment: I noticed that you had asked two questions before and both of them were closed. Please write your question properly using LaTeX and show in details which part you do not understand or get stucked with to prevent your question to be closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group of symmetric invertible matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1979491/group-of-symmetric-invertible-matrices)

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$,
$B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. Clearly, $A,B$ are symmetric and they are elements of $G$.
Then $AB=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$.
Since $AB$ is not symmetric, the set is not closed under multiplication and hence does not form a group.